# Auto layout - The default spacing isn't the same between different for the NSTextField and the NSDatePicker [PIC]

Tags: macos, cocoa, appkit, spacing, autolayout

I am using auto layout to organize my views for me. I am currently in the testing/design phase of a project and I am just trying to get this to work properly.

I have stacked a number of elements inside of a window and I am using the Visual Format Language to space the vertical distance between views.

Here is the VFL:

```
[contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-[findField]-[replaceField]-[popField]-[textView(==60)]-[picker]-[picker2]-[textView2(==60)]-(>=20)-|" options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllLeading metrics:nil views:views]];
```

And here is what it actually is looking like:

[image]

Even though all of the elements are being separated by the same '-' identifier, the actual space is different. It appears as though the NSDatePicker has less offset than all other views in the window.

Why is this?